# multiple file analysis using modules and local variable

Tags: list-manipulation

I have set of files say 1 to 10. Each of these files have 3 subsets like 1-0,1-1,1-2; 2-0,2-1,2-2; and so on. i.e total 30 files in all. I am using the following code to extract the information from all 0th subset:

```
files = Range[1, 10]; 
path = "D:\\20180126-";
a = Length[files];

c = path <> ToString[#] <> "-0.txt" & /@ files; 
d = Table[Import[c[[i]], "Table"], {i, 1, a}]; 

mns[d_] =  Module[{ma}, 
  ma = Table[{
    Total[d[[i]][[1000 ;; 2000]]], 
    Total[d[[i]][[2000 ;; 2500]]]}
  , {i, 1, Length[d]}] /. {x_} :> x
]

e = mns[d]
```

so far so good.  But when I am trying to extract the same information from subsets "1" and "2" using the following code, I am getting the same values as obtained for 0th subset.

```
c = path <> ToString[#] <> "-1.txt" & /@ files;
e = mns[d]

c = path <> ToString[#] <> "-2.txt" & /@ files;
e = mns[d]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here I have another solution which provides me the same result but in a different approach.
       files = Range[4, 
      20]; path = "D:\\20180126-";
       a = Length[files];
      For[i = 0; c = x, i < 3, i++,
      c = path <> ToString[#] <> "-" <> ToString[i] <> ".txt" & /@ files;
     d = Table[Import[c[[i]], "Table"], {i, 1, a}];
       e = Table[{Total[d[[i]][[1000 ;; 2000]]], 
     Total[d[[i]][[2000 ;; 2500]]]}, {i, 1, Length[d]}] /. {x_} :> x;
      Print[e];
        ]

Comment: What if you use: `mns[d_]:=...`? Please lookup `Set` and `SetDelayed`. See linked topic, especially: [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/5478)